# Error al consumir webservice

Tags: c#, webservice, rest, post

Tengo un webservice rest, ahora en c# tengo una funcion que recibe un json en formato string y yo lo mando al webservice, pero el webservice me dice que el json esta mal.

¿Me pueden decir si esta mal?

```
    ///xs
    var exPrecioStockConsulta = new List<Product>();
    exPrecioStockConsulta.Add(new Product()
    {
         //Algunos son int y otros string,estan en una clase Product
        comprobante_tipo = 1,
        emision = "30 - 04 - 2017",
        comprobante_moneda = 2,
        documento_tipo = 6,
        documento_numero = "123132132",

    });
  var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(exPrecioStockConsulta);
   var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("xxxxxxxxxxxx.com");
    var post1 = "data=" + json;
    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post1);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;

    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

    }
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(responseString);
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Este es el json de salida:

```
[{
    "comprobante_tipo": 1,
    "emision": 30 - 04 - 2017,
    "moneda": 2,
    "documento_tipo": 2,
    "documento_numero": "123132132"
}]
```

El mensaje que recibo del servidor, me dice que el json está mal nada mas "Message : Error".

Comment: ¿dónde estás capturando el "Message: Error"?, ¿tienes un `try/catch` en algún lado?

Comment: Message-Error ,viene a ser el mensaje que me da el servidor al enviar los datos,ya que no son validos.
emision: Fecha de emision en DD-MM-YYYY  / \d{1,2}- \d{1,2}- \d{4} /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es el json:

```
"emision": 30 - 04 - 2017
```

Debería ser:

```
"emision": "30-04-2017"
```

Edita en esta parte:

```
exPrecioStockConsulta.Add(new Product()
    {
         //Algunos son int y otros string,estan en una clase Product
        comprobante_tipo = 1,
        emision = "30-04-2017", //Aqui anda tu error.
        comprobante_moneda = 2,
        documento_tipo = 6,
        documento_numero = "123132132",
    });
```

Comment: emision: Fecha de emision en DD-MM-YYYY  / \d{1,2}- \d{1,2}- \d{4} /
Tiene que ser algo asi,pero estaria bien en string?

Comment: ahí con la expresión regular dices que uno o dos dígitos seguido de un guión, seguido de uno o dos dígitos seguido de un guión, seguido de 4 dígitos